# why do we use k-normial tree in cluster network

Tags: networking, tree, broadcast, topology

Why do we need k-nomial tree in network topology, it's faster than binary tree in terms of broadcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a broadcast on a binary tree, the root is idle after he sent two messages. In a binomial tree, the root has more than two neighbours (while the depth of the tree remains the same), therefore nodes don't become idle before the broadcast is finished.